# JS Lint (Htm/Css): Unexpected '-'

Tags: jslint

I have the following div in a Windows 8 app project

```
<div style="-ms-grid-row: 1; -ms-grid-column: 1;">
   Size:
</div>
```

JS Lint gives me the following complaint:
JS Lint (Htm/Css): Unexpected '-'

It would seem that it doesn't like the -ms-grid-row and -ms-grid-column in my style tag.

What can I do to make it stop complaining, either by changing my code or figuring out which setting I need to turn off.

Comment: JSLint is for JavaScript, not HTML/CSS.

Comment: The JSLint plugin I'm using for visual studio 2012 (from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd) appears to cover css/html in addition to JavaScript.

Comment: @gusto - Update JSLint to a more recent version. HTML/CSS support has been removed. If you want to validate them, find a different tool that is designed for the job.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I think you should post this as an answer.